# Making shechayenu twice on megillah

Tags: halacha, purim, megillat-esther, shehecheyanu, cities

If someone was able to put themselves into a situation that they would be required to read the megillah twice (for example they went to Bnei Brak on the 14th of Adar then came to Jerusalem for the 15th of Adar) do they make a shechayanu when the megillah is read then on the 15th?

One could say that since the person already made one on the previous day's reading (whether it be only by night or by day as well) then they wouldn't have to make another one now. Or since every day is looked at as a separate "chiyuv" (requirement) then they would have to read the megillah now again with a shechayanu.

Answer (score 1):

I was told by a Chabad rabbi in Jerusalem that the custom is to say "shechiyanu" if this is the case, since Purim and Shushan Purim are actually different holidays. I think there's probably room to do it either way, though, since obviously the halakhic principle of "no blessing in case of a doubt" applies here as well.